# Appcelerator look for a bootstrap wrong class

Tags: java, android, appcelerator-mobile, bootstrapping

Appcelerator mobile project is looking for a bootstrap file with wrong name. I'm on macosx. I can't resolved it. I don't understand what's happening. This bootstrap class is from an android module that's bulid perfectly.

This is the error:

```
Failed to compile Java source files:

[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /Users/acavero/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/pruebaAdMob/build/android/gen/es/renr/pruebaAdMob/PruebaadmobApplication.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] :       runtime.addExternalModule("ti.admob", ti.admob.AdmobAndroidBootstrap.class);
[ERROR] :                                                     ^
[ERROR] :    symbol:   class AdmobAndroidBootstrap
[ERROR] :    location: package ti.admob
[ERROR] :  1 error
```

The correct name is AdmobBootstrap. At PruebaadmobApplication.java he calls for 2 bootstrap classes:

```
V8Runtime runtime = new V8Runtime();

runtime.addExternalModule("ti.admob", ti.admob.AdmobBootstrap.class); //correct

runtime.addExternalModule("ti.admob", ti.admob.AdmobAndroidBootstrap.class); //Wrong

KrollRuntime.init(this, runtime);
```

Please, help me.Thank you for advance-